# Django Haystack - Show results without needing a search query?

Tags: python, django, search, solr, django-haystack

I would like to display all results which match selected facets even though a search query has not been inserted. Similar to how some shop applications work e.g. Amazon

`e.g. Show all products which are "blue" and between $10-$100.`

Haystack does not return any values if a search query is not specified.

Any ideas how I can get around it?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't suppose you want to vote on/accept answers?

Answer (score 12):

If anyone is still looking, there's a simple solution suggested in haystack code:

https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/forms.py#L34

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    def no_query_found(self):
    """
    Determines the behavior when no query was found.

    By default, no results are returned (``EmptySearchQuerySet``).

    Should you want to show all results, override this method in your
    own ``SearchForm`` subclass and do ``return self.searchqueryset.all()``.
    """
    return EmptySearchQuerySet()
```

Answer (score 6):

### Why No Results?

I imagine you're using a search template similar to the one in the haystack [getting started documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.6/tutorial.html#setting-up-the-views). This view doesn't display anything if there is no query:

```
{% if query %}
    {# Display the results #}
{% else %}
    {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}
{% endif %}
```

The second problem is that the default search form's `search()` method doesn't actually search for anything unless there's a query.

### Getting Results

To get around this, I'm using a custom search form. Here's an abbreviated sample:

```
class CustomSearchForm(SearchForm):
    ...
    def search(self):
        # First, store the SearchQuerySet received from other processing.
        sqs = super(CustomSearchForm, self).search()

        if not self.is_valid():
          return sqs

        filts = []

        # Check to see if a start_date was chosen.
        if self.cleaned_data['start_date']:
            filts.append(SQ(created_date__gte=self.cleaned_data['start_date']))

        # Check to see if an end_date was chosen.
        if self.cleaned_data['end_date']:
            filts.append(SQ(created_date__lte=self.cleaned_data['end_date']))

        # Etc., for any other things you add

        # If we started without a query, we'd have no search
        # results (which is fine, normally). However, if we
        # had no query but we DID have other parameters, then
        # we'd like to filter starting from everything rather
        # than nothing (i.e., q='' and tags='bear' should 
        # return everything with a tag 'bear'.)
        if len(filts) > 0 and not self.cleaned_data['q']:
            sqs = SearchQuerySet().order_by('-created_date')

        # Apply the filters
        for filt in filts:
            sqs = sqs.filter(filt)

        return sqs
```

Also, don't forget to change the view:

```
{% if query or page.object_list %}
    {# Display the results #}
{% else %}
    {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}
{% endif %}
```

Actually, the view code is a little hackish. It doesn't distinguish query-less searches with no results from search with no parameters.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Look at [SearchQuerySet](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#searchqueryset-api).

This should be possible if color and price has been defined in your SearchIndex:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(color="blue", price__range=(10,100))
```

You can limit the query to certain models by adding [`models(Model)`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#SearchQuerySet.models) to the SearchQuerySet. So if you want to limit your query to the model Item use:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(color="blue", price__range=(10,100)).models(Item)
```

Comment: This made me realise where my problem was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following form display all the result if not query string is present. Now you can add custom filters.

```
from your_app.forms import NonEmptySearchForm
url(r'^your_url$', 
SearchView(template='search.html',searchqueryset=sqs,form_class=NonEmptySearchForm), name='haystack_search'),
```

## forms.py

```
#Overridding because the default sqs is always none if no query string is present
class NonEmptySearchForm(SearchForm):
    def search(self):
        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()
        sqs = self.searchqueryset.auto_query(self.cleaned_data['q'])
        if self.load_all:
            sqs = sqs.load_all()
        return sqs
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumpy Joe Pete's answer is pretty spot on, but as he mentioned, the template `if query or page.object_list` check is a little hacked. A better way of solving this would be to create your own `SearchForm` which would still find something if `q` is empty - will not repost that - AND to customize the `SearchView` with something like:

```
class MySearchView(SearchView):
    def get_query(self):
        query = []

        if self.form.is_valid():
            for field in self.form:
                if field.name in self.form.cleaned_data and self.form.cleaned_data[field.name]:
                    query.append(field.name+'='+str(self.form.cleaned_data[field.name]))

        return ' AND '.join(query)
```

In most cases, you won't even be using the `query` value, so you could just as well do a quick check if any of the fields is set and return `True` or something like that.. or of course you can modify the output any way you want (I'm not even 100% sure my solution would work for all field types, but you get the idea).